# Symfony 3 - Add security.authorization_checker in my service 's args cause too many redirects

Tags: php, symfony

I try to create custom listener in my Symfony 3 app.

I want to check if user is IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY or not.

When I add @security.authorization_checker service as arg to mine I get "too many redirect error" to my login route

Does anyone have a working solution in Symfony 3?

security.yml:

```
security:
    providers:
        main:
            entity:
                class: Customer\CustomerBundle\Entity\utilisateur
                property: loginUtil
encoders:
    Customer\CustomerBundle\Entity\utilisateur:
    algorithm: sha1
    encode_as_base64: false
    iterations: 1

firewalls:
    dev:
    pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security: false

    Customer_firewall:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: true
        provider: main            

        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check

        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: Customer_standard_homepage

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/reset, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN : [ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

Services.yml

```
services:
login_listener:
    class: 'Customer\CustomerBundle\Listener\LoginListener'
    arguments: ['@security.authorization_checker', '@doctrine']
    tags:
        - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'security.authentication.success', method: onSecurityAuthentication }
```

LoginListener.php

```
<?php
namespace Customer\CustomerBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;

/**
 * Custom login listener.
 */

class LoginListener
{
  private $authorizationChecker;
  private $em;

  public function __construct(AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker, Doctrine $doctrine)
  {
    $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
    $this->em                   = $doctrine->getEntityManager();
  }

  /**
   * Do the magic.
   * 
   * @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event
   */
  public function onSecurityAuthentication(AuthenticationEvent $event)
  {
    if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
      // user has just logged in
      error_log('here');
    }

    if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
      // user has logged in using remember_me cookie
      error_log('there');
    }

    // do some other magic here
    $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
    error_log('FINALLY HERE');

    // ...
  }
}
```

[image: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS]

Comment: Have you checked what it says in the logs of the profiler?

Comment: I can't acess it, the profiler bar not showing and url `app_dev.php/_profiler` returns `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` too

Comment: If you comment out the service definition (login_listener) it should work again. And then you can click on the "last 10" requests and you should see the failed request to the login_check url.

Comment: There is 3 Infos : 
1/Match login route 2/Anonymous authentication failed.
3/ An AuthenticationException was thrown; redirecting to authentication entry point. i am newest to symfony so i'm not sure to understand what's goin on

Comment: If i comment out if statements into onSecurityAuthentication it works, but i need to know if user is authenticated fully or anonymous then do some stuf, but how ..?

Comment: Anyone could help me ?

Comment: Hmm this is just a guess but maybe the token is not yet in the token storage, so if you use the `AuthorizationChecker::isGranted` method it will throw an exception. You can verify that by checking if the tokenstorage returns a token. If the token is not yet set you can use the `AccessDecisionManager` and use the `decide` method: `if($this->accessDecisionManager->decide($event->getAuthenticationToken(), ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']))`

Comment: as you expected it @vstm `$this->tokenStorage->getToken()` is empty. I tried to use your solution but as I'm new to Symfony I don't know how use the `AccessDecisionManager` into listener register as service. Could you provide me somes examples ? thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the access decission manager like this:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AccessDecisionManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationEvent;

class LoginListener
{
    private $accessDecisionManager;
    private $doctrine;

    public function __construct(AccessDecisionManagerInterface $accessDecisionManager, RegistryInterface $doctrine)
    {
        $this->accessDecisionManager = $accessDecisionManager;
        $this->doctrine              = $doctrine;
    }

    /**
     * Do the magic.
     *
     * @param AuthenticationEvent  $event
     */
    public function onSecurityAuthentication(AuthenticationEvent $event)
    {
        $em = $this->doctrine->getEntityManager();
        if ($this->accessDecisionManager->decide($event->getAuthenticationToken(), ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'])) {
            error_log('here');
        }

        if ($this->accessDecisionManager->decide($event->getAuthenticationToken(), ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'])) {
            // user has logged in using remember_me cookie
            error_log('there');
        }

        // do some other magic here
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        error_log('FINALLY HERE');

        // ...
    }
}
```

And the service definition has to be changed to this:

```
login_listener:
    class: 'Customer\CustomerBundle\Listener\LoginListener'
    arguments: ['@security.access.decision_manager', '@doctrine']
    tags:
        - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'security.authentication.success', method: onSecurityAuthentication }
```

I also changed the constructor a bit, in general when using dependency injection it is good practice to reference an interface if possible. Also the constructor should not do too much stuff (I removed the call to `getEntityManger()` and moved id into the listener).

Comment: Awesome it's work as expected. But I realized that my event `security.authentication.success` is not the best choice for my need. So I decided to use  `kernel.controller` event but now I lost acess to `AuthenticationEvent` to get `getAuthenticationToken`inside `onSecurityAuthentication` . I don't know if I'm clear enough..sorry